# Store variable from input box and display value in p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to take a value from a text input box then then display it on the screen.

I have this block of JS acting on the following HTML

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
 var userName = $('#userNameInput').val();
 $('.userDisplay').html(userName);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userNameInput">
<input value="submit" class="button closepopup" type="button">
<p id="userDisplay">default</p>
```

Currently the program doesn't print the value, but it does store it, as I can print the value to console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `p` has an `id`, you have tu use `#`:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    var userName = $('#userNameInput').val();
    $('#userDisplay').html(userName);
});
```

Comment: You're welcome `:)` And don't forget to accept an answer `;)`

Answer (score 1):

`userDisplay` is an `id` and not `class` so use `#` instead of `.`

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    var userName = $('#userNameInput').val();
    $('#userDisplay').html(userName); // Changes here
});
```

Comment: Glad it worked, Consider upvoting it and marking it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the output `p` tag via a classname, but it has an `ID`.

You need to change this selector:

```
$('.userDisplay')
```

to be:

```
$('#userDisplay')
```